# ZFS ashift property for AWS EBS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, zfs

What is the actual Physical Sector Size of AWS EBS volumes?

EBS advertises physical_block_size and logical_block_size as 512 to the OS

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-17:~$ cat /sys/block/xvdi/queue/physical_block_size 
512
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-17:~$ cat /sys/block/xvdi/queue/logical_block_size 
512
```

We are in the process of migrating to Postgres from RDS to EC2 instances (ZFS on EBS with compression). While creating the zpool, `ashift` value is not given

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-17:~$ sudo zpool create pgstripe /dev/xvdf1 /dev/xvdg1 /dev/xvdh1 /dev/xvdi1
....
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-17:~$ sudo zpool get ashift
NAME      PROPERTY  VALUE   SOURCE
pgstripe  ashift    0       default
```

It is said that value of `ashift=9` might affect performance on modern storage devices. So upon verifying the actual value of `ashift` for the pool, found that it's indeed `ashift=9`

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-17:~$ sudo zdb -U /etc/zfs/zpool.cache 
pgstripe:
    version: 5000
    name: 'pgstripe'
    state: 0
    txg: 21518
    pool_guid: 18259321190878592884
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'ip-172-31-28-17'
    vdev_children: 4
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 18259321190878592884
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 6596053233879303485
            path: '/dev/xvdf1'
            whole_disk: 0
            metaslab_array: 39
            metaslab_shift: 31
            ashift: 9
            asize: 322116780032
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
        children[1]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 1
            guid: 10755479908569617562
            path: '/dev/xvdg1'
            whole_disk: 0
            metaslab_array: 37
            metaslab_shift: 31
            ashift: 9
            asize: 322116780032
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
        children[2]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 2
            guid: 7517133622037333375
            path: '/dev/xvdh1'
            whole_disk: 0
            metaslab_array: 36
            metaslab_shift: 31
            ashift: 9
            asize: 322116780032
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
        children[3]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 3
            guid: 17044638243598443214
            path: '/dev/xvdi1'
            whole_disk: 0
            metaslab_array: 34
            metaslab_shift: 31
            ashift: 9
            asize: 322116780032
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
```

So coming to the actual question

1. What's the actual block size of ebs volumes?
2. Is `ashift=9` is optimised enough for the underlying EBS volumes?
3. For EBS, is `ashift=12` will be more performant than `ashift=9` on pools with `recordsize=128K` considering zfs always performs i/o in 128K blocks?

Already done the postgres load test with this default value of ashift, so going to repeat the same with explicit `ashift=12`.

Answer (score 3):

EBS performance (and in fact, performance of most SSDs) tanks pretty badly if you use ashift=9. You should always use ashift=12 unless you have an overwhelmingly good reason not to.

EBS gives you specific IOPS and it defined an IOP as "up to 16KB".

You will achieve best performance on EBS by enabling lz4 compression, and using as large a record size as you can unless you have a reason to go smaller, as this will make the compression more effective. Reasons to go smaller are typically related to using an application that writes in smaller pages. For example, you might want to set recordsize=16kb for MySQL/InnoDB or recordsize=8kb for PostgreSQL.

But always set ashift=12 unless you have an exceedingly good reason not to, and even then such reasons typically involve increasing the ashift rather than reducing it.

Answer (score 1):

For EBS, the physical disk sector size is completely abstracted away. EBS volumes are networked attached storage. This storage can consist of many thousands of disk drives. Modern SAN controllers can support multiple types of disk drives simultaneously.

In today's disk drives, reported physical sector sizes are 512-byte and 4096-byte. However, this is solely an addressing scheme as the track size is what determines performance. The size of a track on the outer tracks of a disk is larger than the track size on the inner tracks. Some disk drives increase the BPI for the inner tracks but this can have the side effect of higher error rates.

If you think that you can optimize EBS volumes based upon some theoretical sector size, you are wrong. The numbers that you see at this instant in time may be completely different tomorrow. Factors such as the controller, networking latency, networking speed, distance to the physical drive, etc. all have an interplay.

You will get better results by using larger block sizes. The actual physical sector size is no longer a relevant concept. Also, you have no control over the "logical" physical sector size that AWS reports to the VM.